# Flex Scroller on swfloader dying on zoom

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, scroll, zooming

I have a swfloader object on to which i want to zoom into (with respect to a point).... this i achieved with some help on the internet.

But now i notice that when i zoom into a point the scroller on the swf loader doesnt work anymore....

Code i am using below... any ideas on how i could correct this problem???

```
<s:Scroller id="scrollme" width="100%" height="100%" >
    <s:HGroup id="mapView" width="100%" height="100%" clipAndEnableScrolling="true" >

        <s:SWFLoader id="img" autoLoad="true"  addedToStage="img_addedToStageHandler(event)" click="img_clicked(event)" maintainAspectRatio="true" includeIn="normal" />   
    </s:HGroup>
</s:Scroller>
```

and the actionscript bit

```
protected function onZoom(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
        {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            scaleAt(event.scaleX,event.localX,event.localY)
        }
        public function scaleAt( scale : Number, originX : Number, originY : Number ) : void
        {
            // get the transformation matrix of this object
            affineTransform = img.content.transform.matrix; 
                //transform.matrix
            trace("zooming to " + scale)

            // move the object to (0/0) relative to the origin
            affineTransform.translate( -originX, -originY )

            // scale
            affineTransform.scale( scale, scale )

            // move the object back to its original position
            affineTransform.translate( originX, originY )


            // apply the new transformation to the object
            img.content.transform.matrix = affineTransform;
            //checkscroller();

        }
protected function img_addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

            if (!Multitouch.supportsGestureEvents)
                currentState = "normal";
            else 
            {
                currentState = "normal";
                for each (var item:String in Multitouch.supportedGestures)
                {
                    if (item == TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_PAN)
                        img.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_PAN, onPan);
                        /* else if (item == TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ROTATE)
                        img.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ROTATE, onRotate); */
                    else if (item == TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE)
                        img.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, onSwipe);
                    else if (item == TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM)
                        img.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM, onZoom);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you're doing.  You're using SWFLoader to load an image?  Why not just sure the Image component with a source of the url to the image.

Either way, you can't have your HGroup wrapping your component and have clipAndEnableScrolling set to true. Remove that property and you should be good.

Comment: im using an SWFLoader to load PDF file which a service on the net gives me an swf...
the clip and enable scrolling was test.. it doesnt work without that too

Comment: Sounds like the swf that it loads has a weird way of doing it's scaling.  It seems that it scales it for real at first, but then either clip or resizes the view area.  Try loading a normal image or very simple swf to see if it works then.

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:Scroller id="scrollme" width="100%" height="100%" >
    <s:HGroup id="mapView">
        <s:SWFLoader id="img" autoLoad="true"  addedToStage="img_addedToStageHandler(event)" click="img_clicked(event)" maintainAspectRatio="true" includeIn="normal" />   
    </s:HGroup>
</s:Scroller>
```

Comment: This is what I had at first... as i mentioned above... it loads... when i zoom it zooms in.. after that the scroller doesnt work...